# Remove iPad Mini 4 from Find My iPhone without Wi-Fi

Tags: ipad, icloud, find-my-iphone

I want to turn off Find My iPhone on my iPad Mini 4 before sending it in for repair since Apple states:

> If you're unable to turn off Find My iPhone, Apple may not be able to
>   service your device. This policy is in force to prevent unauthorized
>   persons from servicing your device without your knowledge. If you
>   don't remember your Apple ID and Password, please go to iForgot.

However, the Wi-Fi keeps turning on / off by itself before I can turn off Find my iPhone.

Can I do this remotely perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the iPad from your account by visiting [iCloud](https://www.icloud.com) website using a web browser. Follow the below mentioned steps:

1. Visit [iCloud](https://www.icloud.com) website on your computer and login with your Apple ID.
2. Click on **Find My iPhone**.
3. Select your iPad.
4. Click on **Remove from Account** and follow any further steps.

[image: Do this]

---

**Update**: As of this writing, the aforementioned steps to remove a linked Apple device by visiting [iCloud](https://www.icloud.com) website has been revamped. To remove a linked device, follow these steps:

1. Visit [iCloud](https://www.icloud.com) website on your computer and login with your Apple ID.
2. Click on **Settings**.
3. Under **My Devices** section, click on your device (iPad in your case).
4. An overlay view will open, listing all your linked devices. Click on the blue circle with a cross to remove your device and confirm your intent.

Here's what the new UI looks like:

[image]